# 1000 http get requests at the same time and getting both status code and response time

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I am writing a code to test the load by posting 1000 HTTP different requests at the same time taken from a file. Please find the code below. How can I post all the HTTP requests at the same time? Also, I am not sure whether the code which I wrote to get the response time and status is a better one. I am running the requests.get() twice to get the details. Can someone help me to make my code clean by letting me know how to post the HTTP requests at the same time and get both response time and status code? Please find my code below.

```
import requests

urls = []

urls = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('urllist.rtf')]

for url in urls:
    r=requests.get(url)
    time = requests.get(url).elapsed.total_seconds()
    print url, r.status_code, time
```

Comment: This actually causes you to make requests twice. Instead, you can use the saved response: time = r.elapsed.total_seconds()

Answer (score 1):

to make code cleaner, I recommend [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests),

```
pip install grequests
```

you only have to rewrite some parts

```
from __future__ import print_function
import grequests
rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
for response in grequests.map(rs):
    print(response.status_code, response.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

where you get response objects as list in `rs`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It solves my second part. Can you suggest whether i can make the HTTP requests to be posted at the same time using grequests?

Comment: grequests is using `gevent`, which is using lightweight threads, it will perform a parallel requests, check grequests documentation also for more tuning to you conditions, expect a micro sec. delay between requests, an max a sec., all depends on your network, requesting server destination, and your system resources.

Comment: Just to make it sure finally. Does the above code you confirmed makes all the HTTP requests at the same time? I was bit confused since its a For loop.

Comment: One last thing.. Please confirm that all requests are posted at the same time. Is there any method to get the start time of the query post? Thanks..

Comment: @Roshanr yes, you can get `near parallel` requests under conditions i said earlier, and `grequests` also has an exception handling function, where you can catch request exception ! go try it !

Comment: Thanks @sideffect0. My last query to you. Can i capture the start time of each HTTP post. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Roshanr i dont think the library have that option, but all you need is use timedelta using python datetime to get the starttime, from `elapsed_time`

Comment: Hi @sideffect0.. Can you please update the code with timedelta as i am not able to find it out. Will be much appreciated as i am in an urgent position to get this done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use `multiple` `threads` or see `scrappy` https://scrapy.org/

Comment: @Mithilesh..Can i post all the HTTP requests at the same time using scrapy?

Comment: Sorry. Since i havent worked on this scrappy, can you please give me a sample code? Also can i get the status code and response time at the same time?